# How to resize image when click attribute on color swatches change image

Tags: category-attribute, color-swatches

In file list.html image when load page resize 230. but when i click attribute color. size images from 230px to 300px. how can resize images 300px -> 230px



`< img id="product-collection-image-getId(); ?>" 
src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(230);?>helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($ratio_width,$ratio_height); ?>" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>`


[image]